# Remove box shadow from bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

If I don't want to have box shadow on bottom, what do I change my CSS to?

I'm using this, but I have `<sections>` where there's a shadow at the bottom between sections. I don't want that, so I want to get rid of the shadow only on the bottom side though.

Current CSS is:

```
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 19px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 19px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 19px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

Comment: Not possible, because box-shadow is generated based on the entire boundary of the element — you can't select which boundaries you don't want the shadow to be computed... unless you are willing to set a negative offset on the y-axis.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not possible, because box-shadow is generated based on the entire boundary of the element — you can't select which boundaries you don't want the shadow to be computed... unless you are willing to set a negative offset on the y-axis:

```
box-shadow: 0 -19px 19px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```

But that will mean that the shadow will be larger on the top. Another way is to obscure the shadow at the bottom with a pseudo-element, but that presents several problems:

1. Your background will have to be of solid, uniform colour (patterns will mismatch)
2. The shadow will end abruptly at the bottom

The CSS for this fix would be as follow (you might have to adjust the pixel values if you change the shadow blur size).

```
div:after {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    right: -20px;
}
```

See proof-of-concept example below:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

div {
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 19px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/63hhp/

Comment: This worked perfectly, but I removed the -20px from the left and right margins to keep the width accurate and reduced the height to 5px to make it a little more concise.

Answer (score 8):

Use an innerbox (with the shadow) and an outerbox (with an overflow: hidden):

```
<div style="height: 30px; width: 30px; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;">
    <div style="height: 30px; width: 30px; box-shadow: 0 5px 19px 2px #000;">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wQA8D/ (Sorry for the inline css)