# css box shadow on thead that has sticky position

Tags: html, css

I'm styling a table with CSS, I want my `th` has box shadow when its position is sticky. I've tried but I want to get rid the shadow that's in the right (so I'm expecting the shadow only appear in the bottom of the `th` element)

[image]

this is my table CSS

```css
table {
   text-align: left;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
   font-family: $font2;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: 700;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   padding-right: 32px;
   color: #555;
   background: white;
   position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: sticky;
   border-bottom: 5px solid #eee;
   top: 0; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Comment: Unluckily, with just CSS we cannot know when our sticky element has reached its limit, in your case, the top of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with javascript, check the below snippet

```js
const header = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-top');

const rowObserver = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    header.forEach(th => th.classList.add('noShadow'));
  } else {
    header.forEach(th => th.classList.remove('noShadow'));
  }
});

rowObserver.observe(document.querySelector('.observed-row'));
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 20rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  height: 5rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}


.fixed-top {
background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.noShadow {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="fixed-top">Column 1</th>
        <th class="fixed-top">Column 2</th>
        <th class="fixed-top">Column 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Row One</td>
        <td class="observed-row">1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Row Two</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Row Three</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Row Four</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Row Five</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Row Six</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet, but my problem is how to get rid the side shadow of the th element, my sticky works just fine, i just want the shadow effect appear on the bottom of my th

Comment: @RickyOrlandoNapitupulu can you share your sample snippet here or jsfiddle. But one thing we can achieve this by use of javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can understand by the *syntax* below taken from **MDN**:

```css
th{
  /* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

You can decrease the **spread-radius** until the shadow doesn't extend to lefft or right sides.. It will make your shadow a little smaller though

Edit: I think I understand your problem now.. [A similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19524567/10764341)

Summary: It's not possible to use box-shadow like you mention. Just use pseudo-elements to simulate a shadow to the bottom.

I assume you want shadow on each of the `th` boxes, so putting shadow on `tr:has(th)` is not possible